# How to deal with different screen resolutions in CSS?

Tags: html, css, resolution

I am new to UI design- was wondering what the best way to deal with different screen resolutions is when positioning various HTML elements? 
I thought using %ages would be the way forward but turns out it isn't!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at liquid layouts. This deals with an expanding or contracting web page based on a users browser size -

http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/negativemargins/

Comment: isn't the term "screen resolution" closer to pixels per inch? The concern you addressed is probably called "screen size"?

Comment: These links were good, but for people searching in 2018 are a bit out of date -- from 2003 and 2004. Current solution is to use a well-tested framework like Bootstrap, Material Design, or modern technologies like flexbox (that can flip axis horizontal to reverse, for example, at certain screen sizes), CSS Grids, and use of rems, vh, vw, vmin, vmax...

Answer (score 9):

Have a read here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

You'd be most interested in `@media` queries, particularly `max-width` and `min-device-width`

Answer (score 2):

% is the correct way.  If you start using Javascript to detect resolution and adjust design based on that your code is going to turn into tasty meat spaghetti very quickly.

Back in the day I was always told to design with a minimum resolution of 800x600, but nowadays I always go by 1024x768 as a minimum resolution.

Without more specifics about designs, we can't really help more I'm afraid!

Comment: Tom %ages and JS is what I am looking into doing. That seems to me to be the best way.
Any nice examples you can point me to?

Answer (score 2):

check 960grid it's a layout standard that's divisible by the most common screen resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

First see if this works for you.
replace your  tag with this

Now if does, than implement this onload. This will reduce 100% of your headaches and will do a quick hack for laptops with 1366 x 768 screens without damaging the look and feel for newer, bigger and better screens

```
var screenHeight = screen.height;
if (screenHeight < 800) {
  $('body').css('zoom', 0.8);
} else {
     $('body').css('zoom', 1);
}
```