# How to make css elements appear the same place on different resolutions, and screen resize

Tags: css

i'm using this simple css, but elements move on screen re-size, and differentiate monitor resolutions.

```
.header {
 position: fixed;
 top: 15px;
 left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Look into media queries.

Comment: "*Same place*" - in relation to what? The monitor's edges, the viewport..? Because in relation to the viewport that should work, though a resolution change causes the 'pixel-size' to (sort of) change (so yes: media queries for that).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with different screen resolutions in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802888/how-to-deal-with-different-screen-resolutions-in-css)

Comment: "same place" means, on a widescreen its on middle of the page, on an old screen its on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the em unit instead of pixels.

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15em;
    left: 20em;
}
```

1 em is the height of the default font. It is defined by the browser.

Based on your comment to your question I would like to add that you maybe should have a look at the `display:flex` layout property or just on how to center the content of a(n) (div-)element.

Answer (score 0):

In responce to your comment "'same place' means, on a widescreen its on middle of the page, on an old screen its on the right side."(I cannot comment)

I do not understand where you want it to be. If you want to make it appear to be the same distance from the left of the page when the page is re-sized, use left: some%;