# CSS/HTML page breaks down, on other resolutions

Tags: html, css, size, resolution

i have problem with resolutions in my web page. When i create one on my PC and launch it in chrome, everything looks tip-top, but when someone with lower resolution launches it, it looks messy.

Page on my PC:

[image]

Page on different PCs:

[image]

Comment: you need to learn responsive or adaptive layout

Comment: Which one is better?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZPP6HGSP here

Comment: usually you will apply both concepts

Comment: maybe the browser zoom? `Ctrl+0` to reset

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand how the CSS layout works.

Check this post - [How to deal with different screen resolutions in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802888/how-to-deal-with-different-screen-resolutions-in-css)

You should research online for existing blogs and post before posting a question here.

Comment: this is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

It's bec your pc and desktop has different resolution, use chrome inspector and copy these media query from here for different resolution
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/
and check ur device responsiveness